# How can I play music from iTunes library stored on Mac/Windows?

Tags: itunes

I have a Windows 7 desktop machine and a Ubuntu machine too. I may also get a Mac one day.

I have iTunes set up to sync my iPod Touch, iPod and the girlfriend's iPod, but I generally use Ubuntu (she only uses Windows).

How can I listen to my iTunes collection from Windows through my Ubuntu?

I'm really looking for something that does it in a similar way to iTunes over Home Sharing as I don't want to bother setting up shares etc. Plus if I move my collection to another machine, I want to continue to see it with out issues!

I tried installing iTunes through Wine, but it doesn't work. The app loads but UI messed up!

Comment: I've tried several AirPlay softwares (idea being RDP to windows or use iTouch to control iTunes to play to Ubuntu) but none seem to work -- tried AirFoil Speakers (crashes on loading); AirPlay totem plugin (Totem doesn't see plugin) :(

Answer (score 2):

Provided you have installed

[**libavcodec-extra-52**](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libavcodec-extra-52)

from multiverse and your music files are **not DRM protected** most software [media players](https://askubuntu.com/q/42532/3940) including the default player **Banshee** will be able to play the audio files from your iTunes library.

To have acess to these files on the **same machine** you just have to mount the NTFS partition where your music library resides (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/2280/3940) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/q/46588/3940)).

In case these files are on a **different machine** there is no other way than setting up some kind of networking to gain access (e.g. by mounting the network share). This is also the way it is done by the proprietary Apple UPnP-like solution called *"Home Sharing"* that unfortunately is not Open Source and thus can not be made available to Ubuntu. However there is commercial software that allow bridging to a UPnP client (e.g. [Allegro](http://www.allegrosoft.com/ams.html)).

See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/24357/3940) for other solutions to set up a UPnP server that do not involve iTunes.

To have access from Ubuntu your music player needs to be capable of being an UPnP client. This can be achieved for many players, e.g. by installing a plugin.

> **Note:** Setting up a samba share on Windows is likely to be the easiest way when it comes to just gaining access to your library.

Comment: I did mention in my question that I didn't want to mess around with shares. My reasoning is that I have several playlists setup and would lose these (yes I could export them...). The AirPlay solution seems to be the way forward... I just can't get them to work! Thanks though :)

Comment: @neildeadman: I was facing the same issues before I switched my library to be hosted and managed from Ubuntu, so I do know how you feel. In your case where a lot of Apple hardware is involved you unfortunately have a limited choice of open solutions only - if any.

Comment: Yeah, its tough... will sort something I'm sure! :)