# What are ways of sharing music on ubuntu externally?

Tags: music, mediaserver, upnp, daap

I setup a DAAP server on my server at home, mapped to my router. In ubuntu I have a variety of clients that support DAAP. In windows I couldn't find clients or easy ways of connecting to my DAAP server.

What are my options, or best way to access my music from outside?

This thread 
[What are my options for sharing files between Windows & Ubuntu on the same network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24357/what-are-my-options-for-sharing-music-between-windows-ubuntu-on-the-same-netwo) denotes *same network*, bur hints UPnP.

UPnP becomes confusing because, it uses both UDP port 1900 and TCP port 2869, even if I find a server utility,

- how would I add both ports?
- As of now, windows, VLC, and the few media clients that I tried don't let you add a UPnP server manually. However they let you open urls?
- Is there a technology available that will add my library through url??

---

I'll be documenting my progress here. 
**Ubuntu DAAP server using Tangerine**

```
  Windows Clent options: 
          - [Firefly Client][1] : Connection refused. 
          - [Songbird Plugin][2]  : Outdated, doesn't work with version 2.0.0


  Android Clent options: 
          - [DAAP Media Player (Miceli Bros.)][3] : Connects on 3G & Wi-fi
          - [Music Pump DAAP Player (Android Music Pump)][4]   :  Connects on 3G & Wi-fi
```

From the profile of UPnP, it doesn't look like a protocol that allows you to stream from external libraries you physically plugged in [vpn counts] (granted you broadcast properly to subnet).

**On a Local Network [not what i'm looking for]**

```
  DAAP Through VPN and On Local Network: 
          - itunes will detect DAAP server and files, but no options to add manually
          - options above still applicable

  UPnP with PS3 Media Server:
          - Android
                   - [BubbleUPnP (Bubblesoft)][5]: Detects and streams 
                   - [UPnPlay (Bebopfreak)][6]: Detects and streams 
          - Windows
                   - VLC : Sees server, but cannot browse, Crashes Server 
                   - WMP:  Sees server, but shows no content
                   - itunes: doesn't even see Server 
                   - banshee: server listed but greyed out
                   - media monkey: sees sub folders but they empty
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice alternate way is tho use **mpd** to stream your music.

For mpd you may find for most platforms (including smart-phones) a bunch of clients.

Comment: any client you recommend for windows, is this password protected?

Comment: See here for a list of clients: http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Clients.
Personal I recommend gmpc --> http://gmpclient.org/home

Comment: @kmassada If your problem is resolved, don't forget to close this question.