# Ubuntu to Windows storage server

Tags: windows, files

So I have just added an Ubuntu server to my home network that is otherwise composed out of Windows machines.

The computer has two hard disks, `120GB` one with OS and one `320GB` that is currently mounted in home directory.

What I want to achieve is that server can be accessible through Windows explorer as a file folder.

So when someone navigates to the server via win explorer he get to a folder that represents the whole `320GB` disk that can then be used to store and share files with other computers on the network.

Is that possible?

Comment: yes, use samba and ask a more spricifc question - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are my options for sharing files between Windows & Ubuntu on the same network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24357/what-are-my-options-for-sharing-files-between-windows-ubuntu-on-the-same-netwo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Samba**.

Samba is a system for sharing files and folders through your network. To get it, simply run:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Then, you will have to set up shares for your network. You will want to edit the file located at:

```
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

And add in a share entry. For example, if you wanted to share the folder `/home/your_user/share`, the bottom of your `smb.conf` should look like this:

```
[Share]
comment = Shared
path = "/home/your_user/share"
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = your_user
```

To share that folder in a way that Windows can easily create and manage files within it.  Now, on Windows, if you browse your Network, you should see an entry with your Ubuntu server's hostname. You can open that, and all of your Samba shares will show up.

To make it easier to access, you can **Map Network Drive** on your Windows machines. The address for the network drive will look like this:

```
//UBUNTU.SERVER.IP/Share
```

and you can choose any of the available drive letters.